# to get some sleep vs to get enough sleep

Tags: conditional-constructions

Are both sentences are correct? How to say better if I say about sleeping during 8-10 hours - "to get enough sleep"?

> If you go to bed early tonight, you have enough time to get some sleep.
>
> If you go to bed early tonight, you will have time to get enough sleep.

TIA

Comment: You are comparing the zero and first conditional.  So, do you know this for a fact?

Comment: Yes, I know it. If I have some mistakes, please correct them.

Comment: It's not about mistakes.  The first conditional is used for facts, certainty, rather than speculations about what may happen in the future.  Can you replace if with when in the first sentence and retain it's veracity?

Comment: If/When you go to bed tonight, you have sufficient time to get enough sleep........= a fact you know to be certain....................If you go to bed early tonight, you will have sufficient time to get enough sleep.= a prediction of the future that you assume has a high probability of occurring

Comment: Any dictionary should make the difference between ***some*** and ***enough*** quite obvious. And why do the examples randomly switch from ***you have*** to ***you will have**?*

Comment: FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica, you could read my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences specify the same condition: *that you go to bed early*. After that, the meanings are different.

"You will have **enough time** to get **some sleep**"
 means that in the time available, you will be able to sleep. The amount of sleep may or may not be enough.

"You will have time to get **enough sleep**"
means that with the time available, you can get enough sleep.

Comment: Could you say please if I change tenses in the sentences it changes something? Is it only like a fact and a prediction, isn't it?

 If you go to bed early tonight, you will have enough time to get some sleep.

If you go to bed early tonight, you have time to get enough sleep.

Comment: Is it only a fact and a prediction swap, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. It seems to be a conditioned prediction in both cases, but what is predicted is different. "Some sleep" is different than "enough sleep". The "enough time" is stated explicitly in the first prediction, but it is also implied in the second prediction.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your last message. )

Comment: I'm sorry too. I was answering your comment about "a fact and prediction swap". I'm saying both of your sentences are predictions. To understand better, look at the word modified  by "enough". It is different in the two cases. Does that help?

Comment: Your first answer is very good. Thanks. Another ones aren't easy for my English.